# Citrix XenApp - Understanding

Tags: citrix

Can you please help me with my understanding of xen app. Here is my understanding of citrix xenapp - When any virtual application ( such as word ) is started from xen app server, it basically creates a tunnel between the user machine and the xen app server. The xen app server, creates a session for the user and starts streaming the application or hosts the application inside that tunnel / terminal . The user is basically logged in terminally to that session. When the terminal session is establised, it operates through wfc32.exe ? Where does the ICA.exe come into picture in this case. What is WFICA.EXE ? Where is the PNAgent.exe ( on the xenapp server ? )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Citrix Connection Flow]

Some statements to help clarify things

1. Citrix (XenApp) is based on terminal services.  The user *is* logged onto a terminal services session (think **RDP**).  This is displayed in steps [5-7].
2. The web interface is exactly that, something that is presented in a web browser.  You may be aware the application shortcut can also be in other locations.  These are populated / managed by the **PNAgent.exe**

   3. The user's start menu
   4. The user's system tray
3. The *.ica* file, is simply a text file with an authentication ticket to allow the user to connect to the target terminal server.  ICA is a separate protocol to RDP, and on your client *wfica.exe* interprets those ICA files and establishes the connection and everything else that's hapenning client side for that application (screen renderings, mouse events, keyboard events, shortcuts, etc...)

Comment: Great.. Thanks alot for the information provided. Couple of questions what about wcfrun32.exe and pnagent.exe ?

Comment: okay got it , pnagent.exe is part of Web interface. What about wcfrun32.exe , I dont see wfICA.exe in my machine. ( I see wcfrun32.exe ), I assume this must be new version then ?